# `Itertools.cycle`: most pythonic way to take multiple steps?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools

I've got some list, and I'm looking to cycle through it. The trouble is that I'm not interested in cycling through elements one at a time, but I want to cycle through by `n` elements at a time.

For instance, if my list is `l = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, then I would want the following output:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> gen = cycle(l)
>>> next(gen, 4) # I know this doesn't work -- take as pseudocode
d
>>> next(gen, 3)
c
```

I know that I can accomplish this with something like:

```
def generator_step(g, n):
    for item in range(n):
        next(g)
     return item
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be 4 steps? That's not 4 steps on the second call.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed, sorry

Comment: You might want to just maintain a list and an index, for constant-time jumps. You can't get that with an `itertools.cycle` iterator. (`collections.deque` and its `rotate` method might also be worth considering, but that's not constant-time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` to advance the cycle object before calling next:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

c = cycle(l)
n = 4
print(next(islice(c, n-1, n)))
# d
```

Comment: Why does your `islice` function take three arguments? I'm finding the output with `islice(c, n)` to be satisfactory.

Comment: That only gives the first item in the slice when you call `next`, which is not what you want

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation for itertools, there's a [handy recipe for precisely this problem](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```